# Scraping hidden leaderboard data from site

Tags: python, web-scraping

There's a [website](https://community.koodomobile.com) having 2 leaderboard active (week/alltime). Both are loaded in page source but the one that shows by default is weekly. Am trying to scrape the data from the all-time : [HTML source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URHxd.png) But I can't seem to be specific enough since I only get the data from the weekly leaderboard.

Here's script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/Rob/Documents/Python/chromedriver")

driver.get('https://community.koodomobile.com')
time.sleep(5)

# Object is “results”, brackets make the object an empty list.
# We will be storing our data here.
# Add the page source to the variable `content`.
content = driver.page_source
# Load the contents of the page, its source, into BeautifulSoup
# class, which analyzes the HTML as a nested data structure and allows to select
# its elements by using various selectors.
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

# Xpath to alltime : /html/body/div[3]/div[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]
# Xpath to weekly : /html/body/div[3]/div[12]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]

div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'qa-tab-content'})
table = div.find('table', attrs={'class': 'leaderboard-table'})
products = []
for link in table.find_all('a', attrs={'link--user'}):
    products.append(link.text)
for x in products:
    print(x)
driver.quit()
```

Was thinking maybe I could go by Xpath but not supported in BS. So yeah, don't know what my next step is.

Comment: There are 2 `table`s with `class="leaderboard-table"`. Do a `find_all` instead of a `find` on your `soup` object and get the result in index 1.

Comment: Once I found the 2 tables from the page source, how do I specify what data I want after? Seems like the find() fonction gives me an AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? If I change to find_all() gives the same error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL. You can use `requests`/`json` modules to load the data:

```
import json
import requests


url_week = 'https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?period=thisWeek&maxResults=20&excludeRoles='
url_all_time = 'https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?period=allTime&maxResults=20&excludeRoles='

# print for week:

data = requests.get(url_week).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for item in data:
    print(item['name'], item['points'])

print('-' * 80)

# print for all time:

data = requests.get(url_all_time).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for item in data:
    print(item['name'], item['points'])
```

Prints:

```
nim4165 1274
Robert T 1216
Dennis 761
Mayumi 643
Goran 524
Dinh 329
Sophia 279
Philosoraptor 120
Lucas8320 104
Bernard Koodo 100
notYetACustomer 85
Allan M 83
BobTheElectrician 72
Timo Tuokkola 71
Chrisowhy 71
Bernpow 71
LR 70
Wintyer 66
Mpeeg 65
Bailzellia 61
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dennis 52349
Dinh 40790
Sophia 25967
Mayumi 25178
Goran 24552
Robert T 19718
Allan M 19649
Bernard Koodo 14323
nim4165 13305
Timo Tuokkola 11206
rikkster 7338
David AKU 5688
Ranjan Koodo 4506
BobTheElectrician 4124
Helen Koodo 3370
Mihaela Koodo 2764
Fred C 2537
Philosoraptor 2102
Paul Deschamps 1973
Emilia Koodo 1755
```

Comment: @NoobAtPython I've opened Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab and there were two requests which contained the required data.

Comment: What made you look into the Networks tab? I do see the points.leadearbord xhr file in there but would have never thought to look in there. Is there something from the source code that indicated that the data is loaded externally?

Comment: @NoobAtPython I've done `print(soup)` and haven't seen the data there - but the page must get it from "somewhere". Usually, the pages load it through JavaScript/Ajax.

Comment: If it's in the HTML code, it should be in print(soup) too, no? I mean : [here it is](https://imgur.com/O2fW6WM)

Comment: @NoobAtPython Yes, you've probably used `selenium`, which executes javascript. `beautifulsoup` is just parser, it doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: Omg, so many ways to do one simple things. Definitely more to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way for me to take the data extracted and make a table looking like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB2St.png? The grey area being points extracted everytime I run the script?

Comment: @NoobAtPython To not clutter this comment section, I would suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow (where you describe your problem and what you have so far.) Also, consider accepting this answer (the checkmark on the left side).